# How to get dependent zipped solution files using VSTS

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the VSTS API 2018 to retrieve the zipped solution files based on the sourcepath and the sourceversion. To get the sourceVersion I query it using the teamproject name and buildId.

The problem is that I also need to get all the dependent projects. The question is how can I retrieve the teamProject and buildId for all the dependent projects in the zipped solution such that I can get the zipped solution files for them as well. Here is the code for getting the zipped solution file:

```
 internal async Task<string> GetSolutionFromSource(string sourcePath, string sourceVersion)
        {
            var solutionFile = string.Empty;
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tfsUser, tfsPass) })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(tfsServer);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

                    var url = $"DefaultCollection/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContentZipped?path={sourcePath}&version={sourceVersion}";
                    var solution = sourcePath.Substring(sourcePath.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    var directory = CreateDirectory(solution, sourcePath);
                    var zipFile = string.Empty;

                    log.Debug("TFS: streaming zipped solution ");
                    zipFile = $"{directory}\\solution.zip";

                    using (var file = await client.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(zipFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
                        fs.Flush();                       
                    }

                    log.Debug("TFS: Extracting zipped solution to a temp folder");
                    ExtractZip(zipFile, directory);
                    solutionFile = FindSolutionFile(solution, directory);
                    log.Debug("TFS: Found solution file at " + solutionFile);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex);
                    throw ex;
                }

                return solutionFile;
            }
        }
```